# String Index out of range when looking for repeating adjacent elements?

Tags: java, string, binary

I need to Print all instances of a 32 bit binary number where there are no two 1s adjacent to each other.

For example:

```
10101010101010000000101010101010 is valid


01010101010110000000000000000000 is not because there are adjacent 1s
```

Here is what I have.

```
String number;
    boolean valid = false;


    for(int i = 0; i<= 1e32; i++)
    {
         //create binary number
         number = String.format("%32s", Integer.toBinaryString(i)).replace(' ', '0');

         for(int k = 0; k <= number.length() - 1; k++)
         { 
             //check if there are adjacent 1s
             if((number.charAt(k) == '1') && (number.charAt(k+1) == '1'))//I believe error is from this line
             {
                 valid = false;
             }
             else
             {
                 valid = true;
             }
         }
         if(valid == true)
         {
            //Print if there are no adjacent 1s
            System.out.println(number);
            valid = false;
         }
    }
```

This is the index error I receive. I believe the error is coming from when I check the indexes for adjacent 1s, but I cant figure out why it is out of bounds.  Can anyone help?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of    range: 32
at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
at program.program.main(program.java:30)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: This will fail if your String ends with a `'1'`.

Comment: Note that if two adjacent bits are set, then `x & (x << 1)` is nonzero. You would need to special-case for the two most significant bits being set (or use a larger data type to ensure the MSB is zero).

Comment: Isn't `for(int i = 0; i<= 1e32; i++)` an infinite loop?  All `int` values are less than `1e32` (actually `1e31`).  At least your exception saved you from having to wait around until the loop finished.

Comment: @ajb That seemed a little off to me, too.

Comment: Not to judge your methods, but why aren't you using number.contains("11")?

Comment: Actually, even if it were changed to terminate properly, I have my doubts that it would be able to output _all_ 32-bit numbers with the required property in a reasonable amount of time.  If that's really the requirement, a different algorithm may be needed.  (But I could be wrong.  I'd have to try some tests.)

Comment: @CBredlow I did not know about this method.  Still new to java.  This would of saved so much time, thank you.

Comment: Do you know how many such numbers there are?  If my calculations are correct, it's about 3 million.

Comment: @DavidWallace I get 5.7 million.  (About 3.5 million for 31 bits.)  One of us is committing an off-by-1 error, probably.

Comment: @ajb Did I say 3 million?  I meant, umm, 5702887.  My point was though that printing them all was going to take a while.

Comment: @DavidWallace Yep.  I wrote a solution to this (using a different algorithm) that computed all the numbers in 2 seconds, but took so long to output them that I had to kill it before it was 10% done.  (Of course that could be because I was outputting them in both decimal and binary.)

Comment: @ajb Oh, I have them going to a dot-matrix printer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
for(int k = 0; k < number.length() - 1; k++)
```

The line:

```
number.charAt(k+1)
```

will go out of bounds with your current setup, moving past the last element in the array.

Answer (score 1):

When you check the kth element in your array, you are not checking to see if it is the end of the array before you check the k+1th element, which would take you out of bounds of your array.

Answer (score 0):

So basically, you create a binary string from an integer, and want to see if it contains the substring "11". A simpler way to do this would be to search for that with regex or with

```
if(!number.contains("11"))
{
    System.out.println(number);
}
```

It's a little simpler, unless you are trying to get an algorithm down that proves it.